# SSHing with the nobody user

Tags: linux, ssh, freebsd

I am on FreeBSD. Essentially, I am trying to have a php script (run by apache) ssh into another machine. I am running into the problem that nobody does not have a .ssh configuration file and so am getting the error:

Could not create directory '/nonexistent/.ssh'.
Host key verification failed.

Is there a way to work around this? Bonus points if you can do this without root access so I do not need to pay my web hosting company to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to start `ssh` with the following options:

```
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ...
```

That way, `ssh` doesn't try to load and create the `.ssh/known_hosts` file.

Answer (score 1):

The entire idea behind user `nobody` is that he has almost no rights on the host. Nobody is not part of any group. Nobody has no home directory.

Without homedir there is no .ssh dir in a homedir. So this is not going to work **as nobody**.

Possibly you can run the process under an other user? (Though that would require creating another user, which requires root access. Which you stated as undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

What if you assign a shell to the user.  On my system, nobody is assigned /sbin/nologin as the shell.  what if you changed that to /bin/bash.

I have SSHed into a system plenty of times when no home folder exists, it will create it for you, you just need a shell.

Comment: Root access would still be needed to do this.

Comment: Assigning a shell to user nobody would give more options to `nobody`. That might not be bad if the apache/php is the only program using this user. If others also use nobody then you are removing safeties from multiple programs.  Creating a separate user for this would be better from a security point of view.